# How declare a global array one time

Tags: c#, arrays, global

I have a global array but I didn't allocate memory until textbox event change.
How can I consider the array created or not?! I wanna run "new arr[6]" one time.

Thank you

Comment: Until the array is *new'ed*, it will just be null.  You can check for that with an `if` statement.

Comment: you could also use a list instead and initialize it with the new keyword, `List<string> arr = new List<string>;`.  Do this class level you can add remove change, whatever you need anywhere in the class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually add a readonly property or function for accessing information like this and create the underlying data as needed.

```
    private static int[] m_Array;

    public static int[] Arr
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_Array == null)
            {
                m_Array = new int[6];
            }
            return m_Array;

        }
    }
```

Comment: so how you set the array?!

Comment: @Iran_Girl With the code here, you just set the values in it, you don't set the whole array. If that won't work for some reason, let us know more about what you're trying to do, and we may be able to suggest something more appropriate.

Comment: @Iran_Girl: you just need to set a value in the array. For example: arr[0] = 1;

Answer (score 0):

You can do *lazy creation* (allocation, instantiation) with *Lazy<>* class as well:

```
  // Lazy creation of integer array with 6 items (declaration only, no physical allocation)
  private static Lazy<int[]> m_Array = new Lazy<int[]>(() => new int[6]);

  public static int[] Arr {
    get {
      return m_Array.Value; // <- int[6] will be created here
    }
  }
```

Whenever you want to check if value (array in this case) is created or not use *IsValueCreated*:

```
  if (m_Array.IsValueCreated) {
    ...
```